# Can a parallel for loop write to a common matrix?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm not certain what it means for the iterations of a parallel for loop to be independent. Is the following an example of two valid parallel for loops? They write and read the same matrix, but the matrix indices are unique to each iteration.

```
X = zeros(64);
parfor i = 1:64^2
    X(i) = i;
end
parfor i = 1:64
    X(i,:) = X(i,:) .* randn(1,64);
end
```

Comment: Matlab ouputs an error if it is not a valid parallel loop. So, you just have to run that in matlab, and you'll have the answer right away.

Comment: This quote from the docs seems to indicate that Matlab doesn't always warn: "Note   Because of independence of iteration order, execution of parfor does not guarantee deterministic results."

Comment: This just means that the iteration can be done in any order. That has no influence on your case.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know! By "valid parallel loops", I mean "behave as expected".

Comment: Actually I think it does have an influence on this particular case - `randn` depends on the global `rng` state, so its results will depend on where the loop passes run and in what order. (I don't know if the `rng` state gets shipped from parent to workers or they all start with the default seed; either way, there's interaction.) Sounds like the sort of nondeterministic results they're warning against. The `parfor` correctness check probably can't see this because it's affecting hidden global state instead of a sliced variable or object in the workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as `parfor` is concerned, the following three statements can be regarded as equivalent:

1) The iterations of a `parfor` loop must be independent.

2) No iteration of a `parfor` loop may depend on the outcome of any other iteration.

3) The iterations of a `parfor` loop must be able to be performed in any order (from @Oli)

How do these statements compare to a regular loop? In a typical loop from 1 to 8, the 4th iteration, for example, may depend on iterations 1, 2, and 3, since the software can be certain these iterations have already occurred by the time we reach iteration number 4. It must NOT depend on iterations 5, 6, 7, and 8, since the software can be certain these iterations will not have occurred.

In a `parfor` loop, as @Oli states, the loops may occur in any order. They may occur in the following order, for example, 7 3 4 1 2 5 8 6. Or any permutation of these 8 numbers. This implies something very important: **There is no way of knowing before the fact which iteration will occur first.** To see this, just chuck an `fprintf('Up to iteration %d of %d\n', t, T)` inside your `parfor` loop, where `t` is the loop subscript and `T` is the loop upper bound.

The above statement immediately implies the following conclusion: **Since any iteration might occur first, it is critical that no iteration depends on the outcome of any other iteration**. I'll conclude the answer with some examples:

```
X = ones(8, 8)
parfor n = 1:8
    X(:,n) = X(:,n) .* (3 * ones(8,1));
end
```

In this example, `(3 * ones(8,1))` clearly does not depend on any other iteration - being constant with respect to the loop counter. Similarly `X(:, n)` does not depend on any iteration other than the nth. **EDIT:** I previously was using `randn` in the above example - see the discussion in comments provided by @AndrewJanke for why this was a bad idea. What about this situation:

```
X = ones(8, 8);
parfor n = 1:8
    X(:,n) = X(:,n) + (n + 1);
end
```

This is also perfectly valid. Although there is an `n + 1` in the expression, this is not the same as depending on iteration number `n + 1`. Rather it is simply assigning the integer value of the current iteration number, plus 1, to `X`.

Finally, consider:

```
X = ones(8, 1);
parfor n = 2:8
    X(n, 1) = X(n-1, 1) + 1;
end
```

This would be perfectly valid in a regular loop, since iteration number `n-1` will always occur before iteration `n` (assuming we're looping forwards). But in a `parfor` loop, this will cause an error, since iteration number `n` might occur before iteration number `n-1`. The lingo Matlab uses to describe the problem here is called "slicing". Imagine `X` to be sliced up by the loop iterations. Then in the nth iteration, you may only ever refer to the nth slice of `X`.

A final point, if I ever have doubts about a `parfor` loop, I read the section in the documentation entitled: "Parallel for loops in Matlab - overview" (sorry, can't find the corresponding webpage - unusual for Matlab documentation) It describes all the possible variable classifications inside loops, and the restrictions a `parfor` loop places on each classification. What I've discussed in this answer is really only the tip of the iceberg. For example, statements such as `n = n + 1` are also invalid in a `parfor` loop, since `n` is the loop variable, and assignments to the loop variable are not allowed.

Comment: Hmmm. You know, `randn` might be a bad example for this, because it has a side effect on Matlab's global state. It's a PRNG, and each Matlab session starts with the same random seed; each `randn` call advances it. So its output does depend on previous loop iterations; the output of `randn` is a function of how many times it's been called in that session. Each worker is a session, so the results of this code will depend directly on how many workers there are, what order the loops run in, and what else has affected the `rng` state of those sessions.

Comment: That is, I think using `randn` violates the "it is critical that no iteration depends on the outcome of any other iteration" rule, because part of the outcome of an iteration that calls `randn` is that `rng` is advanced, and that is a hidden input to `randn`. This is nondeterminism that the `parfor` check can't catch, so a human programmer needs to either avoid, or ensure that the nondeterminism "doesn't matter". The "right" thing to do here is probably to generate the whole block of rands before the `parfor`, and then slice in to it in loop iterations; then you'll have reproducibility.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I hadn't thought of that! Very clever! I've adjusted the answer accordingly to remove `randn`. I think it would only prove confusing to the reader to incorporate a discussion of the inherent determinism of most random number generators into the above answer.